# Regex: Match keywords in URL but not subfolders

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write Regex to include all pages that have a keyword in URL and exclude pages that have that same keyword in a subfolder.

The tool that I'm using it in is a website audit tool.

Scope:

```
domain.com
```

Include:

```
\<this-keyword\>
```

Exclude:

```
^/this-keyword/.*
```

It keeps telling me that there is no "seed URL". Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A full input string and expected output is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

using the double slash `//` to recognize URL part :

```
(?!\/\/[^\/\n]*\bthis-keyword\b[^\/\n]*\/.*?this-keyword)\/\/[^\/\n]*\bthis-keyword\b
```

[check on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/apOfZh/2)

Comment: it will make the regex clearer if you replace the delimiter by `|`, and transform `\/` into `/`